# Cannot enable Shell extensions after having turned them off (ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

On ubuntu 21.10 after disabling a couple of extensions for troubleshooting gnome-shell RAM usage, I cannot longer enable them.
Using the extensions app the toggle switch results disabled and
the extension cannot be turned on.

[extension app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EViXO.png)

Comment: Try removing the manually installed extension using the Gnome Shell website, then log out and log back in to see if you now can enable

Comment: @vanadium already tried with no success :-( thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Extensions` app, flip the master toggle switch right next to the magnifying glass icon at the top of the panel to turn on the ability to turn on/off individual extensions.

[image]

Comment: it worked thanks!!!!

Comment: wow.. that worked.. found this page as I was typing a request.  I wonder how this got turned off.  I had installed  ibus-gtk ibus-m17n ibus-table and then I noticed it was gone and could not fix.

Answer (score 0):

When an extension is loaded the `dconf` parameter `/org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions` is modified but `dconf` configuration could be locked using:

```
/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks
```

Modify the contained files and then:

```
dconf update
```